# react-spring deck example not working with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-spring

I'm trying to replicate [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j0y0vpz59?file=/src/index.js:0-3350) with NextJS.

The component gets rendered, but the content doesn't. Is SSR simply a limitation for this particular example?

[image: react-overlay-images-react-spring-bug-forked-q26b5]

Comment: did you solve it? I am also having issues with next.js and react-spring

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it this particular issue, however other issues that I've encountered were resolved by [disabling SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)